# Swift - Type does not conform to protocol when using concrete implementation

Tags: swift, protocols

In this code:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    var someVar: String { get }
}

protocol WithTestProtocol {
    var someVarWithTestProtocol: TestProtocol { get }
}

struct TestProtocolStruct: TestProtocol {
    var someVar: String {
        return ""
    }
}

struct WithTestProtocolStruct: WithTestProtocol {
    var someVarWithTestProtocol: TestProtocolStruct {
        return TestProtocolStruct()
    }
}
```

I get the error message:

```
Type 'WithTestProtocolStruct' does not conform to protocol 'WithTestProtocol'
```

Why is it not possible to conform to a protocol with a concrete implementation? Are there good workarounds?

I know, that this code works:

```
struct WithTestProtocolStruct: WithTestProtocol {
    var someVarWithTestProtocol: TestProtocol {
        return TestProtocolStruct()
    }
}
```

.. but I need to use a concrete implementation there because I want to use other stuff of the concrete implementation. I thought, it is a very common case and I`m wondering, why the compiler does not allow this.

Comment: In `WithTestProtocol`, your  `someVarWithTestProtocol` is of type `TestProtocol`, but in the implementation ( `WithTestProtocolStruct`) you're defining it as `TestProtocolStruct`. It should be `TestProtocol` too.

Comment: Yes, I used a concrete implementation because a need the concrete implementation there. Because of the other stuff this implementation has. I thought, it is a really common case and that the compiler should be able to know that `TestProtocolStruct` conforms to `TestProtocol`.

Comment: @Hamish, thanks for the duplicate link, it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of protocol type is `TestProtocol`

```
struct WithTestProtocolStruct: WithTestProtocol {
    var someVarWithTestProtocol: TestProtocol {
        return TestProtocolStruct()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide specific type while using protocol properties.

```
struct WithTestProtocolStruct: WithTestProtocol {
  var someVarWithTestProtocol: TestProtocol {
    return TestProtocolStruct()
  }
}
```

Practically  `TestProtocolStruct` may or may not confirm the  `TestProtocol` compiler  won't allow this.